# How to retrieve value of multi-select custom product attribute?

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute

I created a new drop-down custom product attribute and placed it in an attribute set. and I'm trying to retrieve its **value** programmatically in Magento 2. The name of said attribute is "ee_qty_custom" but for some reason, I always get either 1 or an empty array when I use any and all functions including:

1. getattribute('ee_qty_custom')
2. getattributetext('ee_qty_custom')
3. getData('ee_qty_custom')

Here is the code for some of what I tried
[image]

Comment: did you tried `getEeCustomQty()` ?

Comment: @Pawan This method doesnt show up in my compiler. And the name you put doesn't match the name OR label of my product attribute.

Comment: it is standard way to get attribute..just used name which you put in question.

Comment: @Pawan if you say so, then please provide a coding answer and ill test it and if it works ill mark your answer as the correct one

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer..make sure `Used in Product Listing` set to `yes` in `Storefront Properties` of attribute!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the atrribute value by:

```
<?php echo $_product->getEeCustomQty();?>
<?php echo $_product->getattributetext('ee_custom_qty');?>
```

First code will give you the value of option and second one will give you text. Both code should work.

**Tip:** If your code is not showing on front, make sure you set `Used in Product Listing` to `yes` in **Storefront Properties** of attribute!

Comment: Ive already tried the 2nd line and you can see in the screenshot that it didn't return ANY value.
But I'm now trying the first and i wanted to ask something, given that my attribute is called "ee_qty_custom" is the function supposed to be 
         $this->logger->debug('ok last chance:  ' . $this->product->getEeQtyCustom());
or
         $this->logger->debug('ok last chance:  ' . $this->product->getEe_Qty_Custom());
or
         $this->logger->debug('ok last chance:  ' . $this->product->getee_qty_custom());

Please also note that im using events and observers NOT template files.

Comment: are you able to get default attribute values ? i.e. `geSku()`. the correct one is  `getEeQtyCustom()` and `getattributetext('ee_custom_qty')`

Comment: Actually, and as i said, i was using events and observers. The event I was using only returned the accurate ORDER object not the product object. So Now, it does work but I had to do this "$product->Load($order->getItemId())" IN order to get the object of the product I wanted which in turn gave me the values I needed. So, while your answer isn't correct, its the closest one to it. Thanks for the help!